# Position element horizontally relative to sibling without wrapping div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position, org-mode

I am styling a document produced by org-mode's [HTML exporter](http://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-export.html#HTML-export) to annotate paragraphs with footnotes appear directly adjacent to the content which they annotate, i.e:
[image: Sidenote HTML]

[original page](http://stefan-marr.de/papers/pldi-marr-et-al-zero-overhead-metaprogramming/)

Unfortunately, the orgmode HTML exporter (`ox-html`) only makes a clunky provision for wrapping a paragraphs, block or "section" in a `div` and so the default HTML structure that I am (mostly) stuck with.

```html
<p>
  Item with footnote #1<sup>1</sup>
</p>
<aside>
  <p>Footnote #1: Should be right of previous paragraph</p>
</aside>
<p>
  Unrelated Content
</p>
```

Consequently, obvious solutions wrapping the `<p>` & `<aside>` in a div and setting display `inline`/`table-cell` or `position: absolute` + padding will not work (to my knowledge).

How can I style a section to be inline with it's previous sibling (but no further) or be absolutely positioned (horizontally) relative to it's **sibling**?

#### Summary & Clarifying Remarks

- The `aside` will be directly left of the previous sibling paragraph (`<p>`)
- All of the paragraphs and asides (footnotes) share the same parent element
- Without modifying `ox-html`, every `<aside>` will have a child `<p>`
- I cannot wrap the `<p>` and `<aside>` in a `<div>` that will not be shared by all of the `<p>` elements
- I would like avoid `HTML_CONTAINER` or manually wrap every single footnote and associated paragraph in yet another `#+BEGIN`/`#+END` block

> If you are familiar with org-mode or ox-html, here is the original format I would like to export from.
>
> ```
> Item with footnote[fn:1]
> #+BEGIN_aside
> [fn:1] Footnote #1: Should be right of previous paragraph
> #+END_aside
> Unrelated content
> ```

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: @joshhunt I can, but again would prefer not to

Answer (score -1):

You can put the `style="float:left"` to any paragraph for which you want to put inline the next element and after float you have to put a blank div or anything with `style="clear:both"`. You can also provide the width with the floating element.

```
<p style='float:left;width:30%'>
    some text
</p>

<p style='float:left;width:70%'>
    some text
</p>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```